# ReportLab: align text with KeepInFrame inside Frame not working

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to align a text horizontally and vertically inside a `Frame` using ReportLab.

The problem is that even defining explicitly the arguments `hAlign='CENTER'` and `vAlign='BOTTOM'` for the `KeepInFrame` function, this does not change the default left horizontal alignment and top vertical alignment top.

I am using the latest version of ReportLab (`reportlab==3.6.9`).

Here's a code example:

```
# Import packages
import re
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, KeepInFrame

# Create document
doc = Canvas(filename='test.pdf', pagesize=A4, bottomup=1, pdfVersion=(1,4))

# Text
text = ("""Here is a simple text that should be hAlign='CENTER' and vAlign='BOTTOM'""")
text = re.sub(r'\n', '<br/>', text)
text = Paragraph(text, ParagraphStyle(name='', fontName='Helvetica', fontSize=11, textColor='black', alignment=TA_CENTER), encoding='utf8')
text = KeepInFrame(
    maxWidth=0,
    maxHeight=0,
    content=[text],
    mode='shrink',
    hAlign='CENTER',
    vAlign='BOTTOM',
    fakeWidth=False,
)

# Create ReportLab Frame object
frame = Frame(
    x1=2.5*cm,
    y1=20*cm,
    width=9.0*cm,
    height=1.5*cm,
    showBoundary=1
)

frame.addFromList([text], doc)

# Save document
doc.save()
```

Output:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was able to solve this problem by combining the `Paragraph` with the `Table` functions (instead of `Frame`).

According to [ReportLab's documentation (page 68)](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf):

> All flowables have an hAlign property: ('LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'CENTER'
> or 'CENTRE'). For paragraphs, which fill the full width of the frame,
> this has no effect. For tables, images or other objects which are less
> than the width of the frame, this determines their horizontal
> placement.

Here's a working example of the desired output:

```
# Import packages
import re
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, KeepInFrame, Table, TableStyle

# Create document
document = Canvas(filename='test.pdf', pagesize=A4, bottomup=1, pdfVersion=(1,4))

# Text
text = ("""Here is a simple text that should be hAlign='CENTER' and vAlign='BOTTOM'""")
text = re.sub(r'\n', '<br/>', text)
text = Paragraph(text, ParagraphStyle(name='', fontName='Helvetica', fontSize=11, textColor='black', alignment=TA_CENTER), encoding='utf8')
text = KeepInFrame(
    maxWidth=0,
    maxHeight=0,
    content=[text],
    mode='shrink',
    #hAlign='CENTER',
    #vAlign='BOTTOM',
    #fakeWidth=False
)

# Create ReportLab Table object
table = Table(
        data=[[text]],
        colWidths=9.0*cm,
        rowHeights=1.5*cm,
        spaceBefore=0,
        spaceAfter=0,
        #hAlign='CENTER',
        #vAlign='BOTTOM',
    )

# Set table style
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
        ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'BOTTOM'),
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, 'black'),
    ]))

table.wrap(0, 0)
table.drawOn(document, 2.5*cm, 20*cm)

# Save document
document.save()
```

Output:
[image]